How do I prevent GNOME from linking two windows snapped to the side of the screen using Super + Left / Right
I'm currently working through a tutorial series on Youtube which consists of working with several different apps/windows (for example a file explorer instance and a console instance). I have to do the tutorial on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with the latest GNOME.
Since I only have one screen available and I also want to have the Youtube video on screen at all times want to snap the Firefox window on the left side of the screen and all windows I have to use for the tutorial on the ride side of the screen. I achieve this by doing the following steps:

Super+Left to snap the browser window to the right side of the screen
Ubuntu (or GNOME?) now shows a selection of the other windows I could snap to the right screen. I cancel by pressing Esc
Afterwards, I activate and snap all remaining windows I need for the tutorial to the right side using Super+Right

My issue is that the first window I snap to the right side will be "linked" to the browser window on the left side. This means every time I click into the browser (for example to pause the video on Youtube), the first window I snapped to the right side will be brought to foreground.
For example: if I snap Firefox to the left side and afterwards snap File Explorer first and Console second to the right side, clicking the Firefox windows will ALWAYS bring the File Explorer window to foreground even if I was working in the console window beforehand.
I struggle to get used to this behavior, is there a way to disable it?

This question is similar to: How can I prevent a window switcher from popping up when I drag a window to the edge of my display?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This new feature was annoying me too but I found it's simple to disable:
Go to Settings -> Ubuntu Desktop and turn off Tile Groups at the bottom under the Enhanced Tiling section.
There is also another setting there Tiling Popup which enables or disables the popup selection of another window to choose when you tile a window.

Have you tried any gnome-extensions?
WinTile-Beyond changes snapping behavior.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6970/wintile-beyond/
